# WTX test data for running the maps

Tags: wsdl, mapping, copybook, wtx

I have created a mapping of copybook elements to WSDL fields. And the map was built successfully. But while running the map locally, I am getting either of the two error for the two different operations that I am mapping:

1) For the first mapping: 'Input valid but unknown data found' and in the trace logs I am getting :    INPUT 1 exists (3012 bytes) but has no content.

More details of error:
(Level 0: Offset 0, len 0, comp 1 of 0, #1, DI 000000000001:)
Data at offset 0 ('<retrFunction1'
  of TYPE X'0004' (retrFunction1Request retrFunction1Request Message WSDLService).

INPUT 1 exists (3012 bytes) but has no content.

End of Validation messages for INPUT CARD 1.

(Offset 26130: Map Number 0 (CobolFuncData), DI 000000000000:)
TYPE X'0148' (COBOL_OBJECT Group CopyBook) has been built.

(Offset 26130: Map Number 0 (CobolFuncData), DI 000000000000:)
TYPE X'0124' (000_COBOL_OPERATION Record CopyBook) has been built.

OUTPUT 1 was built successfully.

2) For the second mapping: 'One of more inputs are invalid' and in the trace logs I am getting :   INPUT 1 exists, but its type is in error.

Further for case2 I am getting: 
(Level 3: Offset 0, len 0, comp 1 of 2, #1, DI 000000000001:)
Data at offset 0 ('xmlns'
  of TYPE X'0008' (Prefix XMLS WSDLService).

I think the issue is not with the mapping of WSDL type trees with the COBOL type trees but with the XML Request and Response data that I am using for running these maps locally. Is there any guidelines that I can use to create the correct input and run the map locally successfully in WTX.

PS. I am using creating the type tree by importing WSDL and not XSD. I am not getting the node 'DOC' in the type tree when I imported my WSDL. In this case what type tree level should I be using for creating my map. I have tried WSDLService -> Type -> ~TypeName -> TypeDef and WSDLService -> Type -> ~TypeName -> Seq

Comment: This issue is similar to the IBM post here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013949509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one reason for this issue myself. The reason being that the request XML did not match the type tree level I was using in the mapping for the transformation. The better way to do this mapping if you are using a WSDL instead of XSD (and 'DOC XSD' doesn't show up in your WSDL/XSD type tree) is to use type for your input card as the 'input' for your operation from the WSDL (as n example: Input yourOperationName Operation yourWSDLService).

As a rule, it is most important to fully understand your WSDL and WSDL operation and XSD strutures in order to create mappings for your transformations.